# Iterate through pages in Word and find pages contains image

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to iterate though every page in a word document, check if that page contains an images or not, and do something about that page (Set page margin and insert a break).

```
For Each Page in Document.Pages
   If Page.ContainsImage Then
      Page.TopMargin = 0
      DoOtherStuff
   End If
Next
```

Comment: There are to types of images in word document- one text embedded (`InlineShapes`) and second one floating (`Shapes`). Which one you have in your document?

Comment: Most of images in my document are (Shapes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Document` has a `Shapes` Collection representing all the Shapes. Each Shape has an `Anchor`, using which we can get to the `TopMargin`, and other properties, of the shape's page:

```
Sub JiggleAllShapes()
    Dim shp As Shape

    For Each shp In ActiveDocument.Shapes
        shp.Anchor.Paragraphs(1).Range.PageSetup.TopMargin = 0
    Next shp
End Sub
```

We can get the page number from the `Anchor`:

```
shp.Anchor.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
```

There is a `Pages` Collection but it is not as useful IMO:

```
Sub WhatAboutPages()
    Dim pge As Page

    For Each pge In ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Pages
        'Debug.Print pge.NothingUsefulHere
    Next pge
End Sub
```

With this approach you would have to delve into the `Rectangles` collection and use `RectangleType` to try to determine if the current `Rectangle` is an image.

Comment: +1 for answering the asked question and the needed question.  Page iteration worked perfectly for me.  thanks