# How to identify pages of a document in Word using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to write a VBA code that starts reading data from the first page and then goes to the next page and does some stuff and then goes to the next page until it reaches the last page.

I did a search on the internet but I read that word doesn't work with pages, but it rather works with sections and ranges. Is there a way to actually deal with pages?

Is it possible to write a code to treat each page as a separate section to have a different header and footer?

Comment: It is not really possible. Why do you need to do this? Tell us what you need, then maybe we can help. Usually when people want to process pages in Word, that means they misunderstood something in Word... Anyway, read [this](http://shaunakelly.com/word/word-development/selecting-or-referring-to-a-page-in-the-word-object-model.html), it tells you how you can't use pages. Or try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024209/iterate-through-pages-in-word-and-find-pages-contains-image) solution from another SO question.

Comment: @vacip: I want to write a macro that takes a journal article as a Word file and creates the headers of each page automatically. The headers, with the exception of the first page, should be repeated mod 4, i.e. we have 4 different headers that are repeated sequentially. if page number mod 4 is equal to 1 or 3, the header should be the authors' names, if page number mod 4 is equal to 2, the journal's name should be written in the header and if the page number mod 4 is 0, the running title should be written in the header. I hope you understand what I say.

Comment: Yes, I understand, I have seen your other question. I'm just not sure Word can do that. Actually, Word is not created for this task. It is a word processor, not a pagination software. Maybe you can force it to do this, but it won't be easy. You'd be better off with a software designed for this task in my opinion.

Comment: @vacip: Yes, I have been struggling with this for hours and haven't progressed at all. Do you know any software fit for this purpose? I know that PageMaker and InDesign can work, but is there an appropriate application software that lets me write codes to do automated tasks with them?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really know software like that. :(

Comment: I've posted to your other question, and it appears that one is the relevant topic. My suggestion would be for you to delete this question and concentrate on the other. Please click EDIT there and add the info about "journal articles" to that problem description.

Answer (score 0):

Using for each loop:

`ActiveDocument.Range.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)`

Or:

`ActiveDocument.Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)`